# Why was galena used as a black pigment, when soot is more black and also more abundant?

Tags: art, classical-antiquity

Throughout centuries, starting in antiquity at least, galena (PbS) is reported as a black pigment. This is for painting but also (in Egypt and Rome) as a cosmetic. 
Soot is a more effective pigment though. And while Galena is common for a mineral, it was certainly less trivial than soot was in cultures that always had oil lamps around. Why did they choose galena?

Comment: Lamp Black, which uses soot from burned fat, oil, tar, or resin, has a bluish tinge to the black. Therefore Galena may have been a *truer black*.

Comment: You might find this interesting ['Black Earths': A Study of Unusual Black and Dark Grey Pigments used by Artists in the Sixteenth Century](https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/paintings/research/technical-bulletin/black-earths-a-study-of-unusual-black-and-dark-grey-pigments-used-by-artists-in-the-sixteenth-century). The article that can be downloaded from that National Gallery site states that "the properties of galena place it in the same category as stibnite, bismuth and tin-rich bronze, since it is a grey pigment rather than a true black. "

Comment: Soot was also commonly used as eg ink in Asia. Maybe practical reasons like good dispersant, durability of the resulted paint, hydrophilic or hydrophobic behavior etc may played role.